# Class attributes in Python

Tags: python, class-attribute

Is there any difference in the following two pieces of code? If not, is one preferred over the other? Why would we be allowed to create class attributes dynamically?

**Snippet 1**

```
class Test(object):
    def setClassAttribute(self):
        Test.classAttribute = "Class Attribute"

Test().setClassAttribute()
```

**Snippet 2**

```
class Test(object):
    classAttribute = "Class Attribute"

Test()
```

Comment: I would use the second. It depends if you want to have control over the creation or not. If not I would avoid the lines of code and the extra function call. Also `setClassAttribute` should be a classmethod otherwise it's senseless.

Comment: I agree with wenzul. They are equivalent, but woth #1, if you forget, you will have some interesting errors.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to create a class instance in order to set an attribute of the class, so neither is preferred. Also, what is *your* opinion on the matter?

Comment: Other thing: I would from experience avoid class variables and methods. In most cases if you think the problem again and create another class, the class variables will be eliminated.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/SeanKellyRecoveryfromAddiction

Comment: That's a good guess, it could also be a case of using a class where none is needed. That's a misconception that many programmers hold because they are taught how to OOP but not when to OOP.

Comment: wenzul, could you give an example of eliminating a class variable by creating a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more natural to do it like #2, but notice that they do different things.  With #2, the class always has the attribute.  With #1, it won't have the attribute until you call `setClassAttribute`.

You asked, "Why would we be allowed to create class attributes dynamically?"  With Python, the question often is not "why would we be allowed to", but "why should we be prevented?"  A class is an object like any other, it has attributes.  Objects (generally) can get new attributes at any time.  There's no reason to make a class be an exception to that rule.

Answer (score 5):

First, setting a class attribute on an instance method is a weird thing to do. And ignoring the `self` parameter and going right to `Test` is another weird thing to do, unless you specifically want all subclasses to share a single value.*

<sub>* If you *did* specifically want all subclasses to share a single value, I'd make it a `@staticmethod` with no params (and set it on `Test`). But in that case it isn't even really being used as a class attribute, and might work better as a module global, with a free function to set it.</sub>

So, even if you wanted to go with the first version, I'd write it like this:

```
class Test(object):
    @classmethod
    def setClassAttribute(cls):
        cls.classAttribute = "Class Attribute"

Test.setClassAttribute()
```

---

However, all that being said, I think the second is far more pythonic. Here are the considerations:

- In general, getters and setters are strongly discouraged in Python.
- The first one leaves a gap during which the class exists but has no attribute.
- Simple is better than complex.

---

The one thing to keep in mind is that part of the reason getters and setters are unnecessary in Python is that you can always replace an attribute with a `@property` if you later need it to be computed, validated, etc. With a class attribute, that's not quite as perfect a solution—but it's usually good enough.

---

One last thing: class attributes (and class methods, except for alternate constructor) are often a sign of a non-pythonic design at a higher level. Not *always*, of course, but often enough that it's worth explaining out loud why you think you need a class attribute and making sure it makes sense. (And if you've ever programmed in a language whose idioms make extensive use of class attributes—especially if it's Java—go find someone who's never used Java and try to explain it to him.)

Answer (score 0):

I think #2 feels more natural.  #1's implementation means that the attribute doesn't get set until an actual instance of the class gets created, which to me seems counterintuitive to what a class attribute (vs. object attribute) should be.