# Why I can Assign a attributes to a class instance, even this attributes is not defined in class?

Tags: python, class

What kind of mechanism is behind this?

For example, I can define a class

```
class test:
    string_a="aaa"
```

then I can setup a instance for class test.

```
test_instance=test()
```

later I can assign a `test_attr` to test_instance.

```
test_instance.test_attr="bbb"
print test_instance.test_attr
```

this will print, `"bbb"`

so what is behavior for?  anything conflict to `__init__`?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this means if don't need to make a subclass to represent some special instance case, then I can just append private attributes to the class instance I want to use? so this is good?

Comment: Just learn more from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257379/class-attributes-in-python)  by abarnert, (pythonic, setter, getter)

Comment: It's not clear what you want, but Python doesn't really *have* "private attributes". Just because you *can* add arbitrary attributes, doesn't mean that doing so is a good idea.

Comment: I think I am confused by the setter, getter way to give attributes value, I was trying to find a good way to set value(but not sure how python does this), just like the \@synthesize in objective C. Now it is much clear now, after read post from abarnert  @jonrsharpe, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. Class attributes
2. Instance attributes

It is important to distinguish the difference.

**Class Attributes** as in:

```
class A:
    a = 1
```

will persist with every **Instance** created. That is:

```
a = A()
b = A()
a.a == b.a  # True
```

**Instance Attributes** are typically accessed by *magic methods* called `__setattr__` (to *set* them) and `__getattr__` (to *retrieve* them).

All instances of classes (unless you use `__slots__`) have an internal dict called `__dict__`. You don't have to "declare" attributes on a class in order to set them on an instance.

Have a read of [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: thanks, I know class Attributes is  common attributes to all its instances, like string_a. And test_attr is unique to test_instance only.  What  I am not sure is how to organize them in a good manner when I starting define class, is there any rule to follow?

Comment: There are lots of opinions as well as best practices. Typically you want to model your objects/classes after some kind of representation of the data and attributes you are mutating and their desired behaviours.

Comment: And also how to track this kind of unique(private) attributes? I often get lost when using python IDE to check them, and read class doc.